# Accessing collectionViewCell in a function

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm very new to programming and have a question. When a user taps a button I want to change the elements in a UICollectionView, but I am having trouble accessing the cells in the function. How do I access a cell in a function without the error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

```
func resetDice(_ fourthFlippedDieIndex:IndexPath) {
    //Get the cells for the four cells that were revealed
    let dieOneCell = collectionView(diceCollectionView, cellForItemAt: firstFlippedDieIndex!) as? DiceCollectionViewCell
    let dieTwoCell = collectionView(diceCollectionView, cellForItemAt: secondFlippedDieIndex!) as? DiceCollectionViewCell
    let dieThreeCell = collectionView(diceCollectionView, cellForItemAt: thirdFlippedDieIndex!) as? DiceCollectionViewCell
    let dieFourCell = collectionView(diceCollectionView, cellForItemAt: fourthFlippedDieIndex) as? DiceCollectionViewCell

    let dieOneTurnOne = dieArray[firstFlippedDieIndex!.row]
    let dieOneTurnTwo = dieArray[firstFlippedDieIndex!.row + 4]
    let dieTwoTurnOne = dieArray[secondFlippedDieIndex!.row]
    let dieTwoTurnTwo = dieArray[secondFlippedDieIndex!.row + 4]
    let dieThreeTurnOne = dieArray[thirdFlippedDieIndex!.row]
    let dieThreeTurnTwo = dieArray[thirdFlippedDieIndex!.row + 4]
    let dieFourTurnOne = dieArray[fourthFlippedDieIndex!.row]
    let dieFourTurnTwo = dieArray[fourthFlippedDieIndex!.row + 4]

    dieOneCell!.setDie(dieOneTurnTwo)
    dieTwoCell!.setDie(dieTwoTurnTwo)
    dieThreeCell!.setDie(dieThreeTurnTwo)
    dieFourCell!.setDie(dieFourTurnTwo)

    firstFlippedDieIndex = nil
    secondFlippedDieIndex = nil
    thirdFlippedDieIndex = nil
}
```

I don't think what I am doing right now is even accessing the cell. `let dieOneCell = collectionView.cellForItem(atIndexpath: firstFlippedDieIndex)`
but it resulted in "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your `cellForItem` in the code is different? From the one you wrote in the end?

Comment: currently my `cellForItem` is `dieOneCell = collectionView(diceCollectionView, cellForItemAt: firstFlippedDieIndex!) as? DiceCollectionViewCell` but when I tried `let dieOneCell = collectionView.cellForItem(atIndexpath: firstFlippedDieIndex)` which is similar to how I got a cell in a different project, I got the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context."

Answer (score -1):

So if you want to change collectioView on button tap, maybe it will be better if you **change dataSource** of that collectionView and then you **reload** collectionView

```
dataSource = [1,2,3....]

func buttonAction(){
   dataSource = [3,6,2...]
   collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to change the dataSource. If I try `collectionView.reloadData()` in the function `resetDice` I get the same message: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context."